# How many 6-digit numbers contain exactly three 1s?

Tags: combinatorics

I just was just given this question and the answer to it but can't seem to solve it as I think I am missing something...

I've tried using different approaches such as n!/r!(n-r!) but I have a problem knowing how many options i've got when placing each numbers. Please forgive me as i'm not familiar with combinatorics...

Comment: I'd distinguish between those that begin with $1$ and those that don't.  For those that begin with $1$ you get $\binom 52 \times 9^3$, for example.

Comment: You have to choose three out six places to put the ones and then you can choose any  number but one for the other places. This can be done in ${{6}\choose {3}} \times 9^3$ ways. But now you also counted numbers such as $000111$. So substract those type of numbers.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Sorry to dig up such an old thread, I'm hoping you're still around haha. Your answer was the one I got as well, but it disagrees with the answers below (it is much smaller than the answers posted by other users). Do you know why/what assumption we made that they didn't?

Comment: @JamesRonald: The answer by Hasan Heydari follows the same line of thought but takes more care of auxillary conditions that I mentioned in my comment as well. You can't really call something a 6 digit number if it starts with a 0. So it's better to consider two cases: The first number is a $1$ or the first number is 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Ah okay, I think I can see that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How many 6-digit numbers contain exactly three 1s?

- The 6-digit number begins with 1

  In this case, suppose we have 6 places. The first place fill with 1. The 2 of remanning places must filled with 1 and 3 of them must filled with {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. Thus, we have $\binom{5}{2}\times 9^{3}$
- The 6-digit number begins with {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

  In this case, we have $8\times \binom{5}{3} \times 9^{2}$

At the end, the result is $\binom{5}{2}\times 9^{3} + 8\times \binom{5}{3} \times 9^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

For many of these questions regarding digits I have found that a recurrence can often simplify things.

Any $n$ digit number with $k$ 1s can be formed either:

1. from an $n-1$ digit number with $k-1$ 1s by appending a 1 or
2. from an $n-1$ digit number with $k$ 1s by appending any of the 9 other digits.

Hence the recurrence for the number of $n$ digit numbers with exactly $k$ 1s $a(n,k)$ is:

$$a(n,k)=a(n-1,k-1)+9a(n-1,k)$$

This forms a 2D recurrence array (think "similar to Pascal's Triangle") clearly $a(1,0)=8$ and $a(1,1)=1$ are our two seed values.

\begin{array}{c|lllllll}
& k=0 & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5 & k=6\\
\hline n=1&8 &1 & & & & & \\
n=2&72 &17 &1 & & & &\\
n=3&648 &225 &26 &1 & & &\\
n=4&5832 &2673 &459 &35 &1 & &\\
n=5&52488 &29889 &6804 &774 &44 &1 &\\
n=6&472392 &321489 &91125 &\bbox[#FFA,6px]{13770} &1170 &53 &1\\
\end{array}

Your answer $a(6,3)$ is highlighted above.

$$\text{6 digit numbers with exactly 3 "1"s}=13\,770\tag{Answer}$$

In addition you get all the other counts $a(n,k)$ as a bonus.

In fact, this recurrence is so similar to Pascal's Triangle that you might be able to spot that the entries in row $n$ are the coefficients of the binomial expansion

$$(8+x)(9+x)^{n-1}$$

which are, in general

$$8\binom{n-1}{k}9^{n-k-1} +\binom{n-1}{k-1}9^{n-k}$$

in this case $n=6,\, k=3$ so that

$$\text{required count}=8\binom{5}{3}9^2+\binom{5}{2}9^3=13770$$